# setOnItemClickListener for GridView in PopupWindow doesn't work

Tags: android, gridview, popupwindow, onitemclicklistener

If i have a **GridView** in a normal Activity it works fine. But here I have it in a **PopupWindow**, and I tried everything to get it to work, but onItemClick won't get called! I tried with the following, which were solutions for most people, but *they didn't work for me* (perhaps i've misused them?):

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Part of the activity:

```
bgGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context));
bgGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("CLICK", "ITEM SELECTED " + position);
    }
});
pw = new PopupWindow(layout, posx, posy);
pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); //bgGrid is part of layout
```

And xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >
<GridView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:columnWidth="160dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </GridView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popup_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="closePopup"
        android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 120));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return imageView;
    }
```

The whole popup part is in a PereferenceActivity, where I have a listener which detects a click on Preference and opens Popup. Apparently there can be only one listener, and I can't set onClick to Preference so I don't know how to solve this (onPreferenceClick never detects any clicks). The first listener which calls the popup (the only way I could get that click):

```
images = (Preference) findPreference("prefs_bg");
images.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new BackgroundColorSelector());
```

Click is shown on the screen (I even tried drawSelectorOnTop), but no matter what, click won't get through.

Comment: Is the event getting into the pop up window itself?

Comment: Does ITEM SELECTED ever get printed to logcat?

Comment: @Nathaniel popup window works well, just the clicklistener doesn't

Comment: Can you post the code for the ImageAdapter?  Are you registering any OnClickListeners in ImageAdapter?

Comment: I've added ImageAdapter. I have no click listeners there

Comment: Running your code on my phone produces log statements for ITEM SELECTED just fine.  The only difference is that I am populating my ImageAdapter with my launcher icon.

Comment: And you used it in a PopupWindow? Could you put it somewhere so i can test it?

Comment: @NPike You were right, I have another click listener. I will add it into my question, I hope you can help me solve this

Comment: @BojanKogoj I have the same problem, again, only in a PopupView. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I just made it differently. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

recently face this problem and found solution here

popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

duplicate problem with solution: 
[Cannot execute OnItemClick for GridView in PopupWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107235/cannot-execute-onitemclick-for-gridview-in-popupwindow/2107315#2107315)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a perfect solution for me:

```
popUpWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popUpWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.white));
popUpWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

The first line enables touch event outside popupwindow.

Without the second line touch event will be prevented by the popupwindow.

And the third line solves your problem.

Without the first and the two, the user interface will not response to any touch/click event when happens outside the popupwindow.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the layouts that your ImageAdapter is inflating do not have any OnItemClickListeners registered and/or have android:focussable=false set on the Adapter layouts.

Such as:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:focussable=false 
/>
```

Comment: If you look ImageAdapter, I am not using any layout for image. I don't have any other clicklisteners either